# How to resolve an internet address?

Tags: iphone, xcode, crash

I have a problem: How can I convert (resolve) an ip address (like www.google.com) into ip address (array of byte)? I tried different code but every time the code crash if the address don't exist. There is a way to check also this?

```
+ (void) resolveIPAddress: (NSString*) dnsAddress {
    struct hostent hostentry;
    const char str = [ dnsAddress UTF8String ];
    hostentry = gethostbyname(str);
    char ipbuf[4];
    char *ipbuf_ptr = &ipbuf[0];
    ipbuf_ptr = inet_ntoa(*((struct in_addr *)hostentry->h_addr_list[0]));
    printf("%s",ipbuf_ptr);
}
```

Comment: Please show your most promising attempt that crashes your app, chances are you aren't checking for the error correctly.

Comment: + (void) resolveIPAddress: (NSString*) dnsAddress
{
    struct hostent *hostentry;
    const char* str = [ dnsAddress UTF8String ];
    hostentry = gethostbyname(str);
    char ipbuf[4];
    char *ipbuf_ptr = &ipbuf[0];
    
    ipbuf_ptr = inet_ntoa(*((struct in_addr *)hostentry->h_addr_list[0]));
    printf("%s",ipbuf_ptr);
}

Comment: the code fail when is executed inet_ntoa and the paddles doesn't not exist (example "www.dfdfdfddf.com")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your method tries using the results of `gethostbyname` without checking `h_errno`. When `h_errno` is non-zero, the results in `hostentry` are invalid. Dereferencing them in `inet_ntoa` causes the crash.

```
+ (void) resolveIPAddress: (NSString*) dnsAddress {
    struct hostent hostentry;
    const char str = [ dnsAddress UTF8String ];
    hostentry = gethostbyname(str);
    if (h_errno) {
        NSLog(@"Error resolving host: %d", h_errno);
        return;
    }
    char ipbuf[4];
    char *ipbuf_ptr = &ipbuf[0];
    ipbuf_ptr = inet_ntoa(*((struct in_addr *)hostentry->h_addr_list[0]));
    printf("%s",ipbuf_ptr);
}
```

Comment: Instead gethostbyname(str); I have to use *gethostbyname(str); otherwise I have an error. But the same... When I debug the function with the simulator, I have the crash of the App (if the site doesn't exist) and h_errno is not assigned.

Comment: Fixed! I use struct hostent *hostentry istead struct hostent hostentry; and now it works. Thank you very much!